# In Rails, what causes the 'not_found.html' view from app/views/application/ to be displayed?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, view, error-handling

In my app there is a form that has been causing some users to receive the "We can't find what you're looking for" error page found in `app/views/application`.

The problem is that I and other people on our team have been unable to reproduce the error ourselves by going through the form ourselves in a pre-production environment with the same codebase and filling it out/submitting it with various options configured.

Rails has views for 500, 404, and 422 errors in `app/public` and I think I understand what causes those (500 is for code issues like syntax errors and 404 is for missing views). But I don't understand what this `not_found` view in `public` is or what causes it to be shown to the user.

Comment: Rails throws 404 error when for example resource is not found /posts/10000000000 or route is undefined (go to e.g. /blabla and check by yourself)

Comment: I feel like this can't be a 404 error though because the view that is being shown is not `app/public/404_error.html` but `app/views/application/not_found.html`. Trying to figure out what error code this is associated with

Comment: `app/views/application/not_found.html` that looks like some custom error handling of yours!

Comment: If it is in public folder it most likely is to be server by the production server. Check production server configuration for error handling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rails returns a `404 (not found)` in prodution in cases when you would experience an `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound`or an `ActionController::RoutingError` exception in development mode.

If you want to have the same behaviour in development, change the following line in your environment config to `false`:

```
# in config/environments/development.rb
config.consider_all_requests_local = false
```

Comment: Thanks. Finally discovered the logs for these transactions and it was indeed the `404 (not found)` after `WidgetsController#create` was looking for a record with an `id = 0` instead of skipping what should've been empty.